# jquery to load a new page and post data from an on change event

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, variables

I am building a website that will identify parts based on 10 different measurements.  I am wanting my my onchange event from my first drop down box to do two things. First, I need it to post my selection to a php variable on the next page. second, I want the function to load the next page which will give me another drop down list that only shows the options that also have the same measurement as the first list.  I am basically building 10 pages that just keep adding on to my sql statement that generates my drop down list.  I am just not sure how to send the jquery post to a php variable, and also how to load a new page. I am new to programming, so I am trying to keep this not too complicated.  here is the basics of my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function get() {
                var lengthdata = $('#filter').serialize();
                $.post('spline.php', lengthdata,
                function(output){
                        $('#list').html(output);
                        });
                }           
        </script>   
    </head>     
    <body>
        <div id="id1"></div>
        <?php
        //database login and connection.
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbuser = "root";
        $dbpass = "password";
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("could not connect!");
        $select_db = mysql_select_db('camdb') or die('could not select camdb database!!');
        echo "<style type='text/css'>";
        echo "td {padding: 10px;}";
        echo "</style>";
        echo "<form name='filter' id='filter'><table><tr>";

        echo"<div id='lengthsel'>";
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Length FROM camTable;";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        echo"<td>Cam Length" . "<br/>";
        echo"<select name=\"Length\" id='Length' onchange='get()'>/n";
        echo"<option value=''>Select</option>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['Length'] . "'>" . $row['Length'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select></td>";
        echo"</tr></table></form>";
        echo"</div>";
        ?>
        <div id="list"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is basically what the rest of the pages are

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function get() {
                var splinedata = $('#filter').serialize();
                $.post('spider.php', splinedata, 
                function(output){
                        $('#list').html(output);
                        });
                }           
        </script>   
    </head>     
    <body>
        <?php
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbuser = "root";
        $dbpass = "password";
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("could not connect!");

        $select_db = mysql_select_db('camdb') or die('could not select camdb database!!');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM camtable WHERE ";
        if ($_REQUEST['Length'] != "") {
            $sql.='length="' . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Length']) . '";';
        }

        //$sql.="ORDER BY length, spline, spider, support, head, nose, grov1";
        echo $sql . "<br/>";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM camtable WHERE ";
        if ($_REQUEST['Length'] != "") {
            $sql.='length="' . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Length']) . '";';
        }
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo"<td>Spline" . "<br/>";
        echo"<select name=\"spline\"id='spline' onchange='get()'>/n";
        echo"<option value=''>Select</option>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . row['spline'] . "'>" . $row['spline'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select></td>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a recommendation, don't use `mysql_*` extension anymore, since it's [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) as of php 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){ $('#form1')[0].submit();});
});
```

assuming your select is inside a form as `<form id="form1" action="secondPage.php" method="post">`

and in the second page you catch the value using `$_POST['selectName']`

Comment: OK, That works great, Now, can I send that variable to multiple pages? I am building an SQL query on every page based on the previous selection from the drop down box.  I need to pass my first selection to the next 10 pages(for each query I am writing) My second selection to the next 9 pages, my third selection to the next 8 pages... so that my last page will have 9 values past to it. something like "SELECT * WHERE length=$VAR1 AND WIDTH=$VAR2 AND height+$var3...  so I want ($_POST['Length']) to grab the value on all of the pages.

Comment: yes you can do that, but if you can infer the first 8 selections from the last one (if the sub selections are unique), you only have to pass 1 parameter to the next page

Comment: OK, I am having a hard time figuring this one out.  I cant find any good examples to lead me to where I need to be.  By the time I get to my third page, I am getting errors because my first page passes the selection to the second page, but when I get to the third page, my first value is missing.  I am unsure of how to pass the previous selections together with the new ones.

Comment: put it's value inside a hidden textfield of the same form you are using .. then it will be passed along with the other fields to the third page.

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this. is there a site that you could point me to to see an example of how this is done?